# URL Rewrite Deploy to Production Server

Tags: iis, deployment, synchronization, production, url-rewrite-module

I've finished url dynamic rewrite module on my local computer, iis, everything is working but I have to deploy it to the production server now, which will cause errors. Do you have any idea how to avoid them?
If you have done similar thing before...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of the production server in a virtual machine and try to deploy your rewrite rules there.
[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a simple engine to create a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I do mine within a test vm environment then make my edits to the Production Site off hours to avoid the IIS Restart when saving rules.

If you want to move them up in one piece I have thought of making the edits to the machine.config file but after some discussions with our IT group found that was not a workable solution.  Editing the rules on the Web Servers then testing them after being added is the course I have followed so far.